# Remove permutations from list using vba/Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list like this one:

```
0,4
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,3
3,1
3,2
4,0
```

Where 0,4 is just a permutation of 4,0 - 1,2 a permutation of 2,1 and so on. 
So I want to get rid of what I then consider duplicates.
Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: Are both numbers in the same cell?

Comment: Yes, but I can use text to column and separate them easily. They are all integers between 1 and 81

Comment: Add two new columns using MIN() and MAX()  to re-order each pair of numbers (making "like" pairs identical), copy/paste values and then use Remove Duplicates on the new columns.

Comment: Thanks! You could post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two new columns using `MIN()` and `MAX()` to re-order each pair of numbers (making "like" pairs identical), copy/paste values and then use Remove Duplicates on the new columns